# Requesting ideas for Adventures in Time and Space tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [a question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/25974/4398) about [Doctor Who – Adventures in Time and Space: The Roleplaying Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_%E2%80%93_Adventures_in_Time_and_Space:_The_Roleplaying_Game). So far as I can tell, it's our first.

I gleefully ran to tag it, hoping to use something like "adventures-in-time-and-space" to differentiate this from [The Doctor Who Role Playing Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Doctor_Who_Role_Playing_Game) (and to a lesser extent [Time Lord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Lord_(role-playing_game)))... but that exceeds the 25-character limit.

So I'm here, canvassing suggestions for a clear, concise tag. It should avoid confusion with other *Doctor Who* RPG titles (and shouldn't invoke images of [Inspector Spacetime](http://community-sitcom.wikia.com/wiki/Inspector_Spacetime)), and it should be easy for someone to find/guess when they're tagging a question.

Comment: Update from the future!  The tag limit [has been raised](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7383/the-tag-length-limit-is-now-35-characters-let-us-know-if-there-are-tags-we-sho?noredirect=1&lq=1).  We now use [tag:dr-who-adventures-in-time-and-space] (unless it's been changed since then).

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Now that you mention it... They appear to have re-branded "Doctor Who: Adventures in Time and Space" as "Doctor Who Roleplaying Game," the better to confuse it with 1985's "The Doctor Who Role Playing Game." Maybe we could call it "Doctor Who Roleplaying Game Formerly Adventuring In Time And Space."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>This has [recently been renamed](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7384/1204) from [doctor-who-aitas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who-aitas) to [dr-who-adventures-in-time-and-space](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dr-who-adventures-in-time-and-space) now that the tag limit is 35 characters.</s>

And it's been re-renamed to [doctor-who-roleplaying-game](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who-roleplaying-game) since they changed the name of the game.

Comment: [It is no longer Adventures in Time and Space.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_%E2%80%93_Adventures_in_Time_and_Space:_The_Roleplaying_Game)

Comment: @BESW Well that's a surprise. And also much more convenient for fitting it into the tag name (because doctor-who-roleplaying-game fits just fine.)

Comment: If anybody ever wants to ask a question about "*The* Doctor Who Role Playing Game" from 1985, we'll need to tag it carefully. But even in the face of that unlikely event, this seems like a good tag for the modern game. ([tag:the-doctor-who-role-playing-game-1985]?)

Answer (score 8):

I am the one who added the current tag [doctor-who-aits](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who-aits) and after doing more research I realized that other people include "and" in the abbreviation, so I would suggest it changed to [doctor-who-aitas](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who-aitas).

Comment: I like this idea, and SSD seems to concur!

Answer (score 1):

I think [dr-who-adventures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dr-who-adventures) is pretty ideal. It's got Dr Who in it, so people who start typing Dr Who will see it pop up as an auto-completion, and the adventures part should be sufficient to distinguish it.

Comment: Heresy! Or at least, that's what you'll hear from fans. ;) "Doctor" in "Doctor Who" is never shortened to "Dr". Since tags reflect community usage, we need to maintain the unshortened "Doctor." If need be, a symlink from [[tag:doctor-who-adventures]] (22 chars) to whatever we settle on would serve the typing-discoverability.